How can I interpret a UiCompiledInstruction object?
I am trying to scan the newly created tokens of the solana network, I have managed to obtain the UiCompiledInstruction object but I don't know how to continue, I may have gone to the wrong branch at some point but I'm not sure
Example:
UiCompiledInstruction(UiCompiledInstruction { program_id_index: 19, accounts: [1, 17, 14, 0], data: "ghwrApYeNFint", stack_height: None })
I have searched for information but have not found anything.
